# "nuget restore" Failing in Jenkins on Mac OS X

Tags: jenkins, xamarin.forms, continuous-integration

I have three Xamarin Forms projects that I'm looking to build in Jenkins. Two of the three projects exhibit the issue. I can't see any material difference between the three solution files.

Jenkins is set up on a headless Mac Mini.

After fetching the source from Github, the first command (an `execute shell` step) that's run is

```
/path/to/nuget restore /path/to/Solution.sln
```

This command fails with the following error

```
[Project Configuration iOS] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/bd/kz6_2jyj62nb93mtqvftvh240000gp/T/jenkins4970408928304452056.sh
+ /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.12.0/bin/nuget restore '/Users/buildbot/.jenkins/workspace/Project Configuration iOS/Solution.sln'
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.0' from '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.12.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin'.
MsBuild.exe does not exist at '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.12.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin'.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Archiving artifacts
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have checked the directory mentioned in the error and there isn't an `MSBuild.exe` executable there.

When running the same command manually, the command completes successfully.

What am I missing?

Comment: You can provide your demo link.Maybe your problem is about `Jenkins` used.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. can anyone pls suggest how to fix this?